# Jupyter Notebook Export Python file with dependencies

Tags: python, aws-lambda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have been trying hard to package a piece of Python code to be used on AWS Lambda. The problem is that I need the Python script developed in Notebook to be exported along with its dependencies, otherwise it causes various errors after uploading to AWS Lambda. What is the best way to go about this?

**I want a .zip file with the .py file and all its dependencies**

Comment: [Refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206412/how-can-i-import-and-properly-run-pip-imported-libraries-on-lambda) and the answer, and [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html). that might resolve your problem.

Comment: This is definitely the right answer. I was hoping if I could find something to bundle the files without having to go through the ordeal of zipping it up again and again....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in your question and in comment, `Apex` will solve your problem. Apex lets you build, deploy, and manage AWS Lambda functions with ease.

You can read about it [here](http://apex.run/) and [here](https://github.com/apex/apex) and also watch [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u7spDymJqmc).

Hope it helps.